# asp.net mvc execution performance issues

Tags: asp.net-mvc, performance, c#-4.0

[image: My mvc application has performance problem]

[image: this is a empty action of a controller only with on line code]

```
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        string contents = "this is a test !!!!";

        return View();
    }
```

**from the time line even a empty action it still has 10ms delay from start request to controller executing .**

this is route detail :
[image]

Why time cost from start request to controller execute has so long time, it cost mostly of the total execution time.

This is the web.config content:

```
<validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
<handlers>
  <remove name="ValidatecodeImg" />
  <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_32bit" />
  <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_64bit" />
  <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
  <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_32bit" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness32" responseBufferLimit="0" />
  <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_64bit" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness64" responseBufferLimit="0" />
  <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
  <add name="Glimpse" path="glimpse.axd" verb="GET" type="Glimpse.AspNet.HttpHandler, Glimpse.AspNet" preCondition="integratedMode" />
</handlers>
<modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
  <!--<add name="SpiderFilterHttpModule" type="Bitauto.Utils.SpiderFilter.SpiderFilterHttpModule,Bitauto.Utils.SpiderFilter"/>-->
  <add name="Glimpse" type="Glimpse.AspNet.HttpModule, Glimpse.AspNet" preCondition="integratedMode"/>
</modules>
<rewrite>
  <rules configSource="config\IIS7_UrlWriter\Urlwriter.config" />
</rewrite>
```

Comment: the execution time line produce by glimpse mvc 4.

Comment: for full view of the time line image use this link : [link](http://pan.baidu.com/s/1sj6lUyD)

Comment: What's happening in `review.summary`? Can you post some code? No one's going to be able to help you without more information.

Comment: @DaveWard I have update my post , I have test action Index, the execution still poor . I think the problem is not the code from controll , maybe some config or other aspects affecting the execution performance .

Answer (score 0):

thanks for dave Dave Ward's help, I have check it out , the uncontined time-line of the execution was caused by the glimpse , because It need to gather the server and execution information of the request , this may slow down the action execute time , after I remove the glimpse httpmoudle or set it off , the execution time is cut down to normal .

> So when you use glimpse or other tools to debugging web application, should be carefull of the things : everything has cost .